# Jackson Object Mapper with Custom Escapes have limit on field length

Tags: java, json, jackson, escaping

**Jackson Object Mapper with Custom Escaping return wrong output for Strings larger than 2000 char**

I am using jackson to escape some special characters(<,>,',") from Data. My input is Map of `<Object,Object>`. It is working fine except this special input in which string length is larger than 2000 characters.

Below is Main function where I am using Jackson.

```
    Map<Object,Object> specialMap = new HashMap<>();
    specialMap.put("id", "482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863");
    String result = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        //Escaping Special Characters
        objectMapper.getJsonFactory().setCharacterEscapes(new XMLCharacterEscapes());
        result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(specialMap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here `Result` variable should contain string with escaped values. but for this specific input(`specialMap`) It gives sequence of `\` and `\0` characters which is not expected.

**XMLCharacterEscapes** class

```
public class XMLCharacterEscapes extends CharacterEscapes {
private final int[] asciiEscapes;

public XMLCharacterEscapes()
{
    // start with set of characters known to require escaping (double-quote, backslash etc)
    int[] esc = CharacterEscapes.standardAsciiEscapesForJSON();
    // Five chars are predefined in XML and require escaping
    esc['<'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
    esc['>'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
    esc['&'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
    esc['\''] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
    esc['\"'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
    asciiEscapes = esc;
}
// this method gets called for character codes 0 - 127
@Override public int[] getEscapeCodesForAscii() {
    return asciiEscapes;
}
// and this for others; we don't need anything special here
@Override public SerializableString getEscapeSequence(int ch) {
    return new EscapedSerializableString(ch);
}
}
```

**EscapedSerializableString** class

```
public class EscapedSerializableString implements SerializableString {

private final String stringValue;

public EscapedSerializableString(int i) {
    stringValue = Character.toString((char) i);
}

@Override
public String getValue() {
    return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(stringValue);
}

@Override
public int charLength() {
    return stringValue.length();
}

@Override
public char[] asQuotedChars() {
    return new char[0];
}

@Override
public byte[] asUnquotedUTF8() {
    return new byte[0];
}

@Override
public byte[] asQuotedUTF8() {
    return new byte[0];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/manusa/dcde2b77472005360898) with a working version of your code in a groovy script.

There were a couple of syntax errors in your code, you should also check which version of Jackson you are using.
I don't understand which values should be escaped in your input string, so I added a tag to get escaped.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.SerializableString
import org.codehaus.jackson.io.CharacterEscapes
/**
 * Created by Marc Nuri on 2015-12-23.
 */
@Grab('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13')
@Grab('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13')
@Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4')

Map<Object,Object> specialMap = new HashMap<>();
specialMap.put("id", "<EscapedTag>482863</EscapedTag>,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863");
String result = null;
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
try {
    //Escaping Special Characters
    objectMapper.getJsonFactory().setCharacterEscapes(new CharacterEscapes() {
        private static final int[] esc;
        static{
            esc  = CharacterEscapes.standardAsciiEscapesForJSON();
            esc[(int)'<'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
            esc[(int)'>'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
            esc[(int)'&'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
            esc[(int)'\''] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
            esc[(int)'\"'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
        }

        @Override
        int[] getEscapeCodesForAscii() {
            return esc
        }

        @Override
        SerializableString getEscapeSequence(final int i) {
            return new  SerializableString() {

                private final String stringValue = Character.toString((char) i);



                @Override
                public String getValue() {
                    return org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(stringValue);
                }

                @Override
                public int charLength() {
                    return stringValue.length();
                }

                @Override
                public char[] asQuotedChars() {
                    return new char[0];
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] asUnquotedUTF8() {
                    return new byte[0];
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] asQuotedUTF8() {
                    return new byte[0];
                }

            }
        }
    });
    result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(specialMap);
    println result;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the script output:

```
{"id":"&lt;EscapedTag&gt;482863&lt;/EscapedTag&gt;,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863,482863"}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, looks like I was using older version of Jackson and Character Escapes. Now problem is resolved.